# Specify the color of each residue in a protein (PDB)?

Tags: import, color, chemistry

I'm importing a *.pdb file containing a single protein. *Mathematica* automatically produces a plot of the protein.

I want to specify the color of each residue independently, in this plot. Is this possible?

Additionally, I would like to change the type of plot to "cartoon". How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "cartoon", and, sadly, the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PDB.html) doesn't seem to give much information on the type of ColorFunction that can be used

Comment: @JasonB "Cartoon" is the name given in Pymol and VMD (other protein visualization software) to the [ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_diagram) diagram, with the alpha-helices and so on.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be have many options other than `Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", "Rendering" -> #] & /@ {"BallAndStick",
   "Structure", "Wireframe", "Spacefilling"}`

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so this is what it looks like with standard coloring of the residues:

```
Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", ColorFunction -> "Residue"]
```

[image]

But now, if we want to change the residue colors, we need to change the value of a certain internal color list called `` Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`residueColorRules ``

```
residuelist = {"Gly", "Pro", "Ser", "Gln", "Pro", "Thr", "Tyr", "Pro",
    "Gly", "Asp", "Asp", "Ala", "Pro", "Val", "Glu", "Asp", "Leu", 
   "Ile", "Arg", "Phe", "Tyr", "Asp", "Asn", "Leu", "Gln", "Gln", 
   "Tyr", "Leu", "Asn", "Val", "Val", "Thr", "Arg", "His", "Arg", 
   "Tyr"};
Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`residueColorRules = 
 Thread[residuelist -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[36])]
```

[image]

Now when we import the PDB, it uses the new color list,

[image]

The definition of `` Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`residueColorRules `` will be reset when you restart the kernel.

Comment: That's useful, but I don't want to color by residue type. I want to color by residue number. Each residue with a particular color

Comment: Good luck, there is like zero documentation on the allowable color functions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very hack-ish way of coloring each residue sequentially. The trick is in constructing a `Blend[]` function where the color corresponding to each residue appears twice in the first argument. A slight shift is apparently needed to match up the colors, even if only approximately.

```
n = StringLength[First[Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", "Sequence"]]];
clist = PadRight[{}, n, Values[Association[ColorData[97, "ColorRules"]]]];

Import["ExampleData/1PPT.pdb", 
       ColorFunction -> (Directive[GrayLevel[1/10], Specularity[1/5, 10], 
                                   Glow[Blend[Riffle[clist, clist], # - 1/(2 n)]]] &),
       Lighting -> "Classic"]
```

[image: candied peptide]